# Can the second principal component line of X be seen as the first principal component line of $X^T$?

Tags: pca

I need to find the random vector Y for which second principal component line of X is same as the first principal component line of Y. As the second principal component line is orthogonal to the first, I was wondering if it can be interpreted as the first principal component line of the transpose of X?

Comment: How are "X" and "Y" related??

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, keep in mind that a principal component has size equal to the number of columns in $X$, which is not the same as the number of columns of $X^T$. In fact, I challenge you to come up with an example where this is true, even for one case. If you use

$X = \left(\begin{matrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$

then $X$ = $X^T$, so their principal components are equal, but the second is not equal to the first.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. From the Wikipedia page, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis it seems as though we may see the second principal component as the first principal component of X - X$\gamma_{1}$$\gamma_{1}^T$. Could you please explain this?